# Need of Dentry despite traversal could be done by Inode

Tags: files, filesystems, inode

In Linux, if we have directories represented as special type of files having entry of each file name it has. Obviously, we could traverse and find out paths, then why do we need Dentries to assist us in traversing the paths, in other words, what's the significance of Dentry if its job could be done by inodes itself?

Answer (score 2):

An inode does not have any notion of file hierarchy. It is only associated to a bunch of disk blocks which contain the actual data.

Without dentries, you would not have any hierarchy and inodes would all lie at the root of your FS, and they would have no name, just a number (sort of like `/lost+found` after having your FS corruptions fixed. Sort of...)

So, your question lies on a wrong assumption, that "[dentries'] job could be done by inodes". No, only dentries have a notion of filesystem hierarchy, this can't be done by inodes alone.

Comment: What I meant by saying that  "[dentries'] job could be done by inodes" is...I linux every dir is treated as a file, so starting from the root dir's Inode you can read contents of it similarly do the same for directory inside it until you reach the specified dir. This is how I thought that Inode can do Dentry's job, am I still missing something?

Comment: @SaketBhojane This is exactly how things work internally. A directory is a block of data, akin to a file, except that it is a peculiar file entirely made of... dentries. Things are separated, inodes do not deal with file content: at the inode level, what you see is a bunch of disk blocks (whatever their content) along with metadata (e.g. file attributes). One layer above, you deal with file hierarchy and you start examining the content of the blocks when you meet blocks that are associated to directories.